# AWK command for Multiple Conditions print different columns

Tags: shell, awk

I receive multiple files and I need to extract certain fields from all these files. 
Two types of files that I receive as input, sample contents below:

**File 1**

```
Line 1: ST*835*0001~
Line 2: ABC*I*K*KI*330.33*C*AED*CCP*01*071000013*DA*645906447*1752578509
```

**File 2**

```
Line 1 : ST|835|0103~
Line 2 : ABC|I|330.33|C|01|
```

Below is my script,

```
for file in "$SEARCH_DIR"/*; do
   recamt=$(awk -F'[|*]' '/ABC/{print $4}' $file)
    echo " $recamt " >> $logFile
done
```

I need to print the value `330.33` based on `ABC` but since the columns vary (file 1 is on column 4, file 2 is column 3 ), I am not getting the expected output... How do I achieve this ? Thank you!

I also have another `awk` which uses as below

```
filedate=$(awk -F'*' '/\*HP\*IRX\*/ {print $5}' $file)
```

How would I add the additional condition for `awk -F"|"` along with `"*"` but searching for `"'/\*HP\*IRX\*/"` and `"'/\|HP\|IRX\|/..` Hope I am clear. Thank you!

Comment: one thought came to my mind is to use an if condition and look for the file extension. But I am thinking there gotta be a way to achieve in one liner.. Pls advise

Comment: Is the `Line 1 :` in the files or is it you added it? Also what's your expected output? And what's the criteria since the field numbers vary?

Comment: Can you look at the number of fields and decide what to print?  The lines 1 in each file have 3 fields; not enough to be interesting.  The file type 1 has 13 fields shown on line 2 (and the 330.30 values appears in column 5, not column 4, unless I'm misunderstanding something), while file type 2 has but 5 fields.  Can you use some variant of `if (NF >= 5 && NF <= 8) print $3 else if (NF > 8) print $5;`?  I chose 5 and 8 as the breakpoints on the number of fields; you can choose any suitable alternatives.

Comment: Also, do the files have at most two lines, or do they contain alternating sequences of lines like line 1 and line 2, or some other pattern?

Comment: Thank you @Jonathan Leffler, Yes, I think the if condition should work. I will try and let you know.

Comment: Line 1 is just reference , it's not the actual content from the file. The expected output should be $330.33 ( extracted from both the files irrespective of the position .. $330.33 is just an example value given,  In other words, when I scan these two files for "ABC" string, I need the 5th column to be printed on first file and the 3rd column to be printed from the 2nd file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-liner:
`awk -F'[|*]' '{if($3==330.33) print "/ABC/"$3}' ./* >> logFile`

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the 330.33 is coincidental — that's the value in the sample records, but other records would have a different value in the corresponding position.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Used it as a dummy number. The question itself is not well written.

Comment: If you think the question isn't clear (and I agree it isn't completely clear), it's better to make comments to seek clarification, once you've got enough rep to do so.  Until then, it is often better not to answer than to risk an answer that's completely off course, or to risk an answer that should be a comment.  If no-one's responded after a day or two, then maybe it is OK to go ahead as best you can, but be cautious.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Could not comment. Reputation < 50.

Comment: I noticed that — that's why I added "once you've got enough rep to do so", and suggested what to do when you don't have enough rep.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry if I created any confusion, Yes 330.3 is just an sample value I provided.. I am going to try the recommendation from @JonathanLeffler, .. thanks!